# excel .open method parameters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems assigning parameters to my .open methon in VBA for Excel.
Below code is what I have, all I need is to open specified workbook as read-only and not editable.

How do I set up the parameters to work, Please and Thank You!

```
Dim source As Workbook
Dim projekt, BOM As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim LastBOM As Long

LastBOM = Ark1.Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For count = 16 To LastBOM
BOM = Range("I" & count) 'List of Excel workbooks in active workbook
projekt = "[Path to file on drive]\" & BOM & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open (projekt) '<= This works and open above specified workbook 
                         '   but should be read only and not editable

Workbooks.Open(projekt,ReadOnly:=True,Editable:=False) '<= None of these work
Workbooks.Open(projekt,,True,,,,,,,False,,,,,)
Workbooks.Open(projekt,True,False)
Workbooks.Open("projekt",True,False)
Workbooks.Open(Filename:="projekt",True,False)
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=projekt,ReadOnly:=True,Editable:=False)
Workbooks.Open(Filename:="projekt",ReadOnly:=True,Editable:=False)
Next count
```

Comment: Please not that `Dim projekt, BOM As String` only declares `BOM As String` but `projekt As Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim projekt As String, BOM As String`

Comment: No it is possible to declare multiple variables in one statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement

Comment: @HKG: yes, it is possible, but what PEH is saying that, if you declare more than one variable, you have to specify the type for every variable. In your case, `project` is declared as `Variant`, not as `String`. No a big deal here, but in other cases this can lead to errors.

Comment: @HKG Please note that the link you provide is for VB.NET and not for VBA! These are totally different languages. In VB.NET it is possible but **not** in VBA. In VBA you need to specify a type for each variable otherwise VBA automatically assumes `Variant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation is always a good idea: [Workbooks.Open Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) and use the `ReadOnly` parameter:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=projekt, ReadOnly:=True, Editable:=False
```

Also remove the parentheses if you don't need to return a value. Or return the workbook into a variable using parentheses:

```
Dim OpenedWorkbook As Workbook
Set OpenedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=projekt, ReadOnly:=True, Editable:=False)
```

I recommend the last option because you then can easily access the opened workbook eg by using:

```
OpenedWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. I did visit the Excel .open method page and found it to be lacking in spicific details for a newbie like me.